# How to make prediction with TFF?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

My question is : How can I predict a label of such image with Tensorflow Federated ?

After completing the evaluation of the model, I would like to predict the label of a given image. Like in Keras we do this :

```
# new instance where we do not know the answer
Xnew = array([[0.89337759, 0.65864154]])
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict_classes(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[0], ynew[0]))
```

Output:

```
X=[0.89337759 0.65864154], Predicted=[0]
```

here is how state and model_fn was created:

```
def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch) 

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),client_weight_fn=None)
state = iterative_process.initialize()
```

I find this error :

```
list(self._name_to_index.keys())[:10]))
AttributeError: The tuple of length 2 does not have named field "assign_weights_to". Fields (up to first 10): ['trainable', 'non_trainable']
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer will depend on how `state` was created (was `tff.learning` used? if yes, how was the `model_fn` argument defined?) Could the question be extended with these details?

Answer (score 4):

(Requires TFF `0.16.0` or newer)

Since the code is building a `tff.learning.Model` from a `tf.keras.Model` you may be able to use the [`assign_weights_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/ModelWeights#assign_weights_to) method on the [`tff.learning.ModelWeights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/ModelWeights) object (the type of `state.model`).
This method is used in the [Federated Learning for Text Generation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation) tutorial.

This might look something like (near the bottom, the early portions are an example FL training loop):

```py
def create_keras_model() -> tf.keras.Model:
  ...

def model_fn():
  ...
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(create_keras_model())

training_process = tff.learning. build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, ...)

state = training_process.initialize()
for _ in range(NUM_ROUNDS):
  state, metrics = training_process.next(state, ...)

model_for_inference = create_keras_model()
state.model.assign_weights_to(model_for_inference)
```

Once the weights from `state` have been assigned back into the Keras model, the code can use the standard Keras APIs, such as [`tf.keras.Model.predict_on_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict_on_batch)

```py
predictions = model_for_inference.predict_on_batch(batch)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, when I execute your solution after 10 rounds, I find this error `AttributeError: The tuple of length 2 does not have named field "assign_weights_to". Fields (up to first 10): ['trainable', 'non_trainable']`

Comment: What version of TFF is being used? This error message may mean that `assign_weights_to` is being called inside a function annotated with `tff.federated_computation`, which won't work. It needs to be used on the `state` returned by `initialize` or `next`. See `def keras_evaluate(state, round_num)` in the tutorial mentioned the answer as well, where it calls `keras_model.evaluate` can be replaced with `keras_model.predict_on_batch`.

Comment: Could you include the version of TFF, and the stack trace included with the error message? that will help provide better answers.

Comment: TFF 0.12.0 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 171, in <module>
    state.model.assign_weights_to(model_for_inference)
  File "/home/hp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/common_libs/anonymous_tuple.py", line 138, in __getattr__
    list(self._name_to_index.keys())[:10]))
AttributeError: The tuple of length 2 does not have named field "assign_weights_to". Fields (up to first 10): ['trainable', 'non_trainable']`

Comment: Thanks @Zachary , can you tell me here, what can be batch ? if I have `test_data = [client_datav(n) for n in range(4)] ` .

Comment: The answer above may require a newer version of TFF, likely something after `0.16.0`. In the question the method to construct `sample_batch` would work to create batches. It should be a nested structure in the format the model expects.